# How do I run a node.js app as a background service in Alpine Linux?

Tags: node.js, service, alpine-linux

When I used ubuntu there is a file like this

```
[Unit]
Description=Node.js Web Http Server

[Service]
PIDFile=/tmp/myserver-99.pid
User=user
Group=sudo
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/
ExecStart=/home/user/server.js

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then it was added to autorun with the command

```
sudo systemctl enable myserver.service
```

But now it was decided to use Alpine Linux and there the OpenRC init system is used.

Need to rewrite the script launch file as a background service in Alpine Linux.

Found an article that explains how to start or stop background services in Alpine Linux:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-enable-and-start-services-on-alpine-linux/

Comment: Have you tried [docker](https://www.docker.com/)? There are alpine builds for node.js. [docker node](https://hub.docker.com/_/node)

Comment: I am not using docker
Alpine Linux used as a desktop system

Answer (score 3):

My new file "my-server" which work on openrc

```
#!/sbin/openrc-run
command="node /home/user/server.js"
pidfile="/run/${RC_SVCNAME}.pid"
command_args="-p ${pidfile}"
name="my-server"
description="my-server"
```

And then type command

```
rc-update add my-server
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.